# GAE remote api: RemoteApiInstaller install always fail

Tags: java, google-app-engine

[GAE remote API for java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi#Configuring_Remote_API_on_an_App_Engine_Client) :Configuring Remote API on an App Engine Client

```
RemoteApiInsideAppEngineExample(String username, String password)
        throws IOException {
        // Authenticating with username and password is slow, so we'll do it
        // once during construction and then store the credentials for reuse.
        this.options = new RemoteApiOptions()
            .server("your_target_app_id.appspot.com", 443)
            .credentials(username, password);
        RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
        installer.install(options);
        try {
            // Update the options with reusable credentials so we can skip
            // authentication on subsequent calls.
            options.reuseCredentials(username, installer.serializeCredentials());
        } finally {
            installer.uninstall();
        }
    }
```

In my test it always throw exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: charset may not be null or empty
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.EncodingUtil.getString(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.apache.commons.httpclient.util.EncodingUtil.getString(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.AppEngineClient$Response.getBodyAsString(AppEngineClient.java:138)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.getAppIdFromServer(RemoteApiInstaller.java:318)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.loginImpl(RemoteApiInstaller.java:278)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.login(RemoteApiInstaller.java:239)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiInstaller.install(RemoteApiInstaller.java:106)
```

.....

I'm sure the username and password is admin one, I use GAE 1.7, Federated Login, High Replication Datastore.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the answer, i use federated login, and currently GAE remote API does not support federated login---so bad that i spent much time on debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The code was working on me. You Just need to be sure that your replace the **"your_target_app_id"** by the applicationID